# How to get rid of a hiss in my Behringer Q802USB?

Tags: microphone, noise, mixer, usb, hiss

I recently purchased a [Behringer Xenyx Q802USB](https://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_xenyx_q802_usb.htm), which I intend to use for inputing three [Rode Wireless Go](https://www.thomann.de/gb/rode_wireless_go_ii.htm) mics into my computer. I am using these [adapters](https://www.thomann.de/gb/the_tbone_headphone_adapter.htm) to use the "line in" inputs. But the Behringer has a horrible background hiss, which I can hear directly from the headphones and even if there is nothing plugged in. To make it more precise, here is a list of observations:

1. When nothing is plugged in and all the volumes are down except for the headphones, I can hear a very low background noise which I think is quite normal;
2. When I turn the main mix knob up, the hiss already appears and is already quite loud to my mind.
3. If I turn the level of channels 3/4 or 7/8 up, it becomes slightly louder but not much unless I put the level at the max. If I turn the level of channel 1 or 2 up (the inputs with the mics), it is significantly louder even at a reasonable level. Of course the noise adds up, so if I put several channels at a non-zero level (as I intend to do) it becomes more noticeable.
4. If I plug in the microphones, the hiss is very high compared to the input level. In general the volume is quite low and to have it at a reasonable level I must put some gain, which results into a high background noise.

From what I have read, some people say it is typical of Behringer, however I want to believe that this can be improved otherwise the mixer is just useless. It is also recommended to install the drivers (note that all the observations above are done on the mixer though), but for Mac there does not seem to be any and the sound is just as bad in the headphones and on the computer.

Any idea on what I can try?

Comment: I can only guess you've not got enough gain to be pushing mic signals through line jacks, but I don't know any of the components, so I can't be certain. I wouldn't be surprised a £45 Behringer would be noisy, but I think you could probably push it a bit harder.

Comment: @Tetsujin "I can only guess you've not got enough gain to be pushing mic signals through line jacks": so you are saying that maybe the Xenyx is not suited for those mics, is that right?

Comment: You shouldn't be pushing mics into a line level input. It's a bad match.

Comment: @Tetsujin Mm okay but the noise is there and loud even when the mics are not plugged in.

Comment: Well, that's the cheap mixer - but pushing it harder will reduce that relatively.

Comment: As Tetsujin said, you are not using the kit correctly, and you are using cheap kit, so noise is to be expected. You should not use Line inputs for mics in any case.

Comment: To me your item 1 is the killer: intrinsic (white) noise without anything attached to it (I assume: even without adapters and wireless devices, and not cabled to anything else besides power, right?). // I so, you can't get rid of it, e.g. by filtering. Best case, it's specific to this device: then returning it for a replacement might help. Worst case: it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

This could be by system design/specification.

Please check the documentation: https://images.static-thomann.de/pics/atg/atgdata/document/gettingstarted/281982_8849976360990.pdf

Specifically pay attention to these details:

[image]